# Optimizing save time for bulk save in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a use-case(most common i guess), where i have to insert 300k records, which is everyday refresh, i have used spring jpa save (using batch), currently it is taking more than 1hr to save all records.

I have used batching, but it dint helped much, database is mariadb
is there any better approach for this optimize save time.

Comment: This shouldn't take so long, I wonder if other queries are causing a read lock on the table you're trying to create the entries. Maybe try to post some code, entity and repository call etc, it might be useful.

Comment: Might also want to look at your chunk size if you are actually using Spring Batch

Comment: The lower the chunk size, the more writes it's going to need to make. So like a chunk size of 5 or 10 is going to take a long time, but if that's increased to 1000 or 10000, it should be a lot faster. Also if using something like a paging item reader, to get the data, I would suggest making the page size the same as the chunk size

Comment: Just to make sure you use `saveAll`, as both `save` and `saveAll` got @Transactional, so a lot of calls to `save`, takes longer than single `saveAll`.

Comment: Thank you all for response, I have tried above all, and went with jdbcTemplate for insert, it drastically reduced time to 90%.